Is there any simpler way to describe a function with the following conditions?
Is there any simpler way to describe a function with the following conditions?
$$
f: \{1,2,3,\ldots, 8,9,10\}\to \{A,B,C\}
$$
such that

$n(\{x|f(x)=A\})=5$
$n(\{x|f(x)=B\})=3$
$n(\{x|f(x)=C\})=2$


I can'r read you function description or do you mean f(5)=A  etc.? what das the n  in front mean?

The number of preimage of A is 5.

Let $f_0(x)=A$ for $x\in {1, \dots, 5}$, $f_0(x)=B$ for $x\in {6, 7, 8}$ and $f_0(x)=C$ for $x\in {9, 10}$. Then $f$ is given by $f_0 \circ \varphi$ where $\varphi$ is a bijection from ${1, \dots, 10}$ onto itself. Not sure this is simpler, but is an equivalent way of stating the conditions.

how to generalize $f(x)$ without the subscript 0? There are $\frac{10!}{5!3!2!}$ ways to describe $f_i(x)$.
